# Passing generic objects as method parameters in parent and child - Integer cannot be converted to E

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Here is my situation which I can't get it to work.

```
public class A<E extends Comparable<E>> {

    E e;
    void setE(E e1){ 
        e = e1; 
     }
}

public class main{

      public static void main(String[] args){

              A<Integer> aObj = new A<Integer>

              aObj.setE(some_e);  // works perfectly

              C cObj = new C();

             // this is what I want to do or something similar but it doesnt work because of the failure shown below
             cObj.readSomeFileToGetE(aObj); 

     }
```

However I have another class which really needs to set E and not main (because it reads a file and has a lot of convenient related code) which has a parent child hierarchy as below:

```
public class B{

     public <E extends Comparable<E>> void readSomeFileTogetE(A<E>);

}

public class IntB extends B() {

   //This derived class will only cater to Integers. Similar sibling classes will cater to Floats, etc.

    public <E extends Comparable<E>> void readsomeFileTogetE(A<E> aObj){

           //buffered reader defined to read a file that store an integer
           String xyz = br.readline();

           Integer some_e = Integer.parseInt(xyz);

           aObj.setE(some_e); // fails saying Integer cannot be converted to E. 

    }

}
```

public class FloatB extends B() {

```
   //This derived class will only cater to Floats. 

    public <E extends Comparable<E>> void readsomeFileTogetE(A<E> aObj){

           //buffered reader defined to read a file that store an integer
           String xyz = br.readline();

           Integer some_e = Float.parseFloat(xyz);

           aObj.setE(some_e); // will fail as well. 

    }

}
```

In essence I have to get a generic object passed as a parameter to a child class.

I come from a C programming world where passing voids seem more easier but here in Java the strong typed syntax is making it much more harder.

Is it possible to do what I plan on doing in Java? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Read the error message. It's pretty clear. You have an object of type A<E>. Its method setE() takes an E as argument. You're passing an Integer. So that can't compile. If you want to call setE() with an Integer as argument, then `aObj` should be of type A<Integer>.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Don't abbreviate your code with `...` show what you are *actually* doing.

Comment: It is because Integer does not extend Comparable<Integer>

Comment: @JB Nizet, sure I do understand what is going on here and the error. What beats me is the same works in main but when I pass the object in the method and then try to set from there it fails. How is that any different? Or how do I pass the integer generic i created in main to the method in Class C?

Comment: No, the same doesn't work in main. in main, aObj is of type A<Integer>. Not of type A<E>. You can put eggs into a box of eggs. You can put chocolates into a box of chocolates. You can't put eggs into a box of chocolates, beause the box is for chocolates, not eggs. Same here. I could probably suggest a corrct design **if** you posted a complete minimal example, without unknown methods and abbreviations everywhere.

Comment: @JB NIzet, I am probably not asking the right question. I understand what is going on here but what I dont understand is how do I code the thing to pass the Integer generic I created in main to the function in Class C. is my function declaration wrong then?

Comment: Yes. The B **class** (and not its method) should probably be generic. And C should extend B<Integer>. I'massuming that C and IntB are in fact the same thing. Everything would be so much easier if you posted a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I edited the code fragment to include the gist. This is all I am doing, I have a parent class and child classes that read Integers from a file, Floats from a file and so on. Each derived reader will read from appropriate file and manipulate as needed.

Comment: I just need to understand how do I define the function in both parent and child class to receive a generic object of either int or float.

Comment: Have you read my previous comment? It explains what you should do. Have you tried doing it? Is there something you don't understand in that comment?

Comment: Just read, was busy retyping the code, thanks for the input. I will try your approach. 
And yes C is a typo, i meant B obj = new IntB().